# Why if $n\geq1$ and $0\leq i\leq j\leq n$ then $F_n^j\circ F_{n-1}^i=F_n^i\circ F_{n-1}^{j-1}$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

**Why if $n\geq1$ and $0\leq i\leq j\leq n$ then $F_n^j\circ F_{n-1}^i=F_n^i\circ F_{n-1}^{j-1}$?**

We know that an n-simplex $\mathbb{\Delta}_n$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ given by $\mathbb{\Delta}_n=\{(t_0,...t_n)\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}:\sum_{i=0}^{n}t_i=1;  t_0,t_1,...,t_n\geq0\}$, and also $F_n^i:\mathbb{\Delta}_{n-1}\to \mathbb{\Delta}_n$ is such that $F_n^i(t_0,...,t_{n-1})=(t_0,...,t_{i-1},0,t_i,...,t_{n-1})$ where the zero is put in position $i+1$. I have tried to prove what I want in the following way:

$(F_n^j\circ F_{n-1}^i)(t_0,...,t_{n-2})=F_n^j(F_{n-1}^i(t_0,...,t_{n-2}))=F_n^j(t_0,...,t_{i-1},0,t_i,...,t_{n-2})=(t_0,...,t_{i-1},0,t_i,...,t_{j-1},0,t_j,...,t_{n-2})$

But on the other hand I get that

$(F_n^i\circ F_{n-1}^{j-1})(t_0,...,t_{n-2})=F_n^i(F_{n-1}^{j-1}(t_0,...,t_{n-2}))=F_n^i(t_0,...,t_{j-2},0,t_{j-1},...,t_{n-2})=(t_0,...,t_{i-1},0,t_i,...,t_{j-2},0,t_{j-1},...,t_{n-2})$

So I do not know how I can conclude that $F_n^j\circ F_{n-1}^i=F_n^i\circ F_{n-1}^{j-1}$, could someone help me please, thank you very much.

Comment: Your calculation seems to assume $j\leq i$ instead of $i\leq j$ as your question states.

Comment: @EricWofsey 
I have already corrected that, what else can I do?

Comment: In your first calculation, you've put the second zero in the $j+1$th position, not the $j$th. Since the face maps are affine, I think it's easier just to see how they act on vertices.

Comment: @Matematleta 
Ohh! I already realized the error, with this the result is already followed because the second calculation is fine! Thanks!

Comment: You have to explain what $F^{-1}_{n-1}$ is. This occurs when $0 = i = j$.